# Pandas Print Empty Data Frame with headers

Tags: python, pandas

This is probably pretty basic question, but I am stuck here. I would like to print a empty pandas dataframe on console with headers. I will try to explain it here.

I create a dataframe with a dictionary and print it, it prints the data with headers.

```
>>> details = {'EmpId' : [1, 2],'EmpName' : ["A", "B"]}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(details)
>>> print(df)
   EmpId EmpName
0      1       A
1      2       B
```

But if for some reason dataframe is empty, then it just prints Empty DataFrame.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Emp Id', 'Emp Name'])
>>> print (df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Emp Id, Emp Name]
Index: []
```

Question here is - is it possible to display something like below

```
>>> print(df)
    EmpId  EmpName
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DF_01=pd.DataFrame(columns=['Emp Id', 'Emp Name'])
DF_02=details = pd.DataFrame({'EmpId' : [1, 2],'EmpName' : ["A", "B"]})
        
def PrintDF(Dataframe):
  if len(Dataframe.index)==0:
    Strs=''
    for i in Dataframe.columns:
      Strs+=str(i)+'  '
    print(Strs[:-1])
  else:
    print(Dataframe)
```

`PrintDF(DF_01)` output:

```
Emp Id  Emp Name
```

`PrintDF(DF_02)` output:

```
     EmpId EmpName
0      1       A
1      2       B
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `to_markdown()`.

For empty dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Emp Id', 'Emp Name'])
print(df.to_markdown())
```

Output:

```
| Emp Id   | Emp Name   |
|----------|------------|
```

For dataframe with data:

```py
details = {'EmpId' : [1, 2],'EmpName' : ["A", "B"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(details)
print(df.to_markdown())
```

Output:

```
|    |   EmpId | EmpName   |
|---:|--------:|:----------|
|  0 |       1 | A         |
|  1 |       2 | B         |
```

Refer https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_markdown.html for more table formatting details.

Comment: Thanks Azhar. Markdown seems to return string. Is there any option to get it as data frame itself so that I can use it for further processing?

Comment: You've `df` as dataframe. What are you trying to achieve?